# Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Unable to locate the below `xpath` in `selenium webdriver`.

it doesn't contain id and also tried with css selector but no change

```
Xpathe:- /html/body/div/div/ng:view/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/nav/div[2]/div/ul/li[2]/a

css selector:-html body.ng-scope
 div div.container ng:view.row div.ng-scope 
div.container 
div.tabbable 
div.tab-content 
div.tab-pane 
div.ng-scope nav.navbar 
div.collapse 
div.nav ul.dropdown-menu li a.ng-binding.
```

Please let me know if any one faced this type of issue.

Answer (score 0):

we have different methods to uniquely identify the element if there is no ID/Text

I would suggest you to identify the element which is above/below/next to the element which you are looking for with text and using xpath methods like following-sibling/preceding methods and identify the element.. It really works.

for example:
1. Open firefox browser
2. open "https://au.yahoo.com/?p=us"
3. Here I am just giving an example of "following-sibling" xpath method to identify the element "Web" in the yahoo page for your reference.

`//a[text()='Yahoo!7']/../../following-sibling::div/div/div[1]`

You can implement the same method and try to identify the element even-though if it is not having id/text.
Hope this will help you....please revert me if you have any issue